# image comes with fade-in/fade-out effecta and image change every a fixed time in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have 4 images. I want to load image in first screen. Each image comes with fade-in/fade-out animation and image change after every 10 second. when we click any images than next screen come up.

please give me help i am new in iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will suggest you to go through Apple's **PhotoScroller** sample code.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080